The analytic continuition of the inverse of a complex polynomial.
I'm reading one of the Smale's theses about Alpha theory: Computational Complexity on the Geometry of Polynomials and a Theory of Cost. He mentioned two facts:
Theorem 1: Let $f\in \mathbb{C}[z]$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f'(z)\neq 0$. Then there exists a power series $f_z^{-1}$, such that:

$f_z^{-1}$ is centered at $f(z)$, sending $f(z)$ to $z$.

$f_z^{-1}$ is a compositional inverse of $f$ in its radius of convergence, which is given by
$$ r(f,z)=|f(z)-f(\theta_*)|,\quad \exists \ \theta_* \ s.t. \ f'(\theta_*)=0.$$


Theorem 2: $f_z^{-1}$ can be analytically continued to  the entire complex plane minus $k$ radial slits from $f(\theta_{i_1}),\dots ,f(\theta_{i_k})$ to $\infty$ for some minimal collection $\theta_{i_1},\dots,\theta_{i_k}$ of the critical points of $f$.
My question is: How can we deduce theorem $2$ from theorem $1$? I guess there may be some general conclusions about this in complex analysis? Any references or solutions are welcomed.
By the way, Smale gave a reference for theorem $1$. I would appreciate it if someone has other accessible references/ proofs.
Thank you!
Edit: I forgot to point out: in theorem 2, we assume $f(z)=0$ and $f'(z)\neq 0$.

Reading about the Mittag-Leffler star may be of use to you.

In the Theorem 1 it should be $f'(z) \ne 0$, I believe.

@AndreyZherdev Yes, sorry for the mistake.

I sketch the idea of the proof of Theorem 2.
First we remove from the plane the radial slits starting from all points $w = f(z)$ where $f'(z)=0$, thus we obtain simply connected domain $G$. Now take some function element $(f^{-1}, D), D \subset G$. It follows from Theorem 1 that $(f^{-1}, D)$ admits unrestricted analytic continuation in $G$, that is, for any path $\gamma$ with initial point in $D$ there is a analytic continuation of $(f^{-1}, D)$ along $\gamma$. By the Monodromy theorem for any path with initial point $a \in D$ and end point $b \in G$ analytic continuation along it gives the same value of $f^{-1}(b)$. Therefore all such continuations define a single-valued analytic function in $G$.

Thank you for pointing out Monodromy theorem! By the way, could you please recommend some references to learn the details of this theorem and related stuff for analytic continuation? I am unfamiliar with these. :)

@Zoudelong, I think this theorem can be found in almost every complex analysis course, I can recommend, for example, John Conway's "Functions of one complex variable" part 1.
